# budlesconfig,cs and identity MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello Hope someone can either help or tell this isn't possible

im trying to use the following code

```
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new UserDb()));

    var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()); ;
```

to obtain the current user that's logged in. this code works perfectly on a controller within MVC 5 but I am trying to use this on BundlesConfig.cs so that I can use a certain sass styles page for a certain user set.

If this isn't possible on here I know of other ways but thought this would be easier on here.

Big Thanks

Comment: BundlesConfig.cs runs at application start and the bundle is fixed for the lifetime of the AppDomain so there is no user in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the build processes will not let you use the user identity this early on within the MVC framework

You need to user this either in a controller model or razor view

there is no way to use this in .cs bundle page.

Answer (score 1):

Change the styles on the view instead of trying on the `BundlesConfig.cs`.

I believe its way to early to get user context in `BundlesConfig.cs`

Comment: Actually not a bad shout, I can still load then in the bundles right? but on actually read it when needed?

Comment: Yeah, build the bundles then when you're are the view level and have determined what you need to determine for `currentUser`, load the specific bundle only when needed..